# Giving acces only to a part of a VStudio project to a TFS developer and compiling locally the whole app

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

Is there any way to allow the user to view/change only some files/classes of a .NET project and compile the whole application on the local machine with TFS2010?

Without splitting the project in multiple DLLs, of course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions on folders or individual files in TFS.

But, that is going to take some effort to maintain (e.g. when a new file is added, which permissions should be applied), and would be easy to break.

Better to solve as a organisational/people problem, starting with: why do you want such a restriction?

Comment: @Richard: you want such restrictions if you hire temporary a contractor and don't want him/her to steal your IP.

Comment: If they have read access (e.g. to build and debug the project), then they can copy it. If you don't trust the contractor enough to follow contractual restrictions on IP, then you can't trust them not to hide something in the code.